# Cucumber-Appium - Where to store Hooks if initialising driver in @Before

Tags: java, cucumber, appium, cucumber-jvm

I'll try to explain how I've built this, I imagine something obvious may jump out.

I'm relatively new to this but am building a cucumber-appium framework and am running into some trouble. Currently, I initialise my Appium driver in my @Before hook which is in a GlobalHooks class which contains all Hooks. I have altered the hook so part of it only runs at the start of the test run as Cucumber doesn't support global hooks and I don't see why I should initialise the driver before every test (I'm using Junit so cannot take advantage of TestNG's @BeforeSuite feature).

To take advantage of Appium's parallel sessions, I now want to make my driver (declared in a GlobalHooks class and defined in the @Before method in that class) non-static and it's presenting issues across the suite.

Is it wise to define my driver in a Hook like this if I want my Page Classes to use this driver? Or does anyone have any advice on how to initialise non-static drivers so they can be used to run parallel Appium sessions?

This is probably more of a Java question than about Cucumber or Appium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a stripped down version of using selenium drivers in parallel. It should be similar to adopt to appium driver. This uses pico-container for object creation and sharing across a scenario. Need to add cucumber-picocontainer dependency.

`DriverFactory` stores all the drivers in a ThreadLocal variable `drivers`.

```
public final class DriverFactory {

    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> drivers = new ThreadLocal<>();
    //To quit the drivers and browsers at the end only. 
    private static List<WebDriver> storedDrivers = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                storedDrivers.stream().forEach(WebDriver::quit);
            }
          });
    }

    private DriverFactory() {}

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return drivers.get();
    }

    public static void addDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        storedDrivers.add(driver);
        drivers.set(driver);
    }

    public static void removeDriver() {
        storedDrivers.remove(drivers.get());
        drivers.remove();
    }   
}
```

---

Exists solely for allowing pico-container to create the required driver. Checks if driver already exists for thread to reuse. To avoid this case you can look at extending `ThreadLocal` class and setting up the `initialValue()` method.

```
public class SharedDriver {
    public SharedDriver() {
        if (DriverFactory.getDriver() == null) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path/to/chromedriver.exe");
        DriverFactory.addDriver(new ChromeDriver());
    }
    }   
}
```

---

```
public class GoogleHomePO extends LoadableComponent<GoogleHomePO>{

    @FindBy(name="q")
    private WebElement searchTextBox;

    public GoogleHomePO() {
        DriverFactory.getDriver().get("https://www.google.com/");
        PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), this);
    }

    public void enterSearch(String search) {
        searchTextBox.sendKeys(search);
    }
}
```

---

The `SharedDriver` class needs to be added to any one step definition constructor in the project. As cucumber initializes all the step and hook classes for each scenario picocontainer will instantiate the driver object if required and store it in the DriverFactory.

```
public class StepDefinition {

    private GoogleHomePO gmPO;

    public StepDefinition(SharedDriver driver, GoogleHomePO gmPO) {
        this.gmPO = gmPO;
    }

    @Given("Go to google page")
    public void given() {
        gmPO.get();
    }

    @When("Enter search {string}")
    public void when(String search) {
        gmPO.enterSearch(search);
    }    
}
```

---

Feature file 1

```
Feature: 

  Scenario: First
    Given Go to google page
    When Enter search "From Feature One"

  Scenario: First Again
    Given Go to google page
    When Enter search "From Feature One Again Again"
```

---

Feature file 2

```
Feature:

  Scenario: Second
    Given Go to google page
    When Enter search "From Feature Two"
```

---

POM settings

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                            </includes>

                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response. I've tried adding the driver factory and it seems to work (in the sense that app opens on both phones), although it only runs on one (the last to open). Am I missing something regarding cucumber threading? I followed your [blog](http://grasshopper.tech/283/) and am updating my junit runner class with the --threads command but no joy.

Comment: How are u executing the test? I am using failsafe maven plugin. Have added the POM configuration to the reply.

Comment: If the last driver is only used then there is probably a static driver used. The blog refers to using cucumber without any runner. The option "--threads" only works in that case. It will not work with a runner. Check this out for running cucumber in parallel using maven and  [junit](http://grasshopper.tech/464/)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that latest blog post. I'm using surefire but I'll see if I can add failsafe

Comment: I was also testing running scenarios in parallel, but I'll add a second feature file to my test run to take into account junit can only run features in parallel

Comment: U can use surefire also. The parallel configuration settings should be same.

Comment: Testng will run scenarios in parallel irrespective of feature files. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v4.0.0/testng/README.md

Comment: Thanks again, I left a comment on the blog entry about multithreads not been implemented.

Comment: @JordiLaForge Will have a look. Do u have a link of the sample code to figure out whats happening?

Comment: I got it working, my bad. Sorry about the delay, was away for the weekend. Using AppiumDriver presents some issues though, as the new driver won't each time be the same driver (e.g. ChromeDriver).
I initially had a class to create a new driver for each device I had attached and tried adding each to the DriverFactory but having issues. I'm currently knee deep in ThreadLocals and Pools which I'm sure there is an answer there somewhere. I'd prefer to not create a new AppiumDriver each time (takes a while to create the driver) so when I was working with single thread, I'd just reset the app.

Comment: Anyway, I think this is on me to crack this. Thanks very much for your input, your blog is great for this kind of stuff. I'll post again if I get it

Answer (score 0):

@Grasshopper. Coming back to you because I said I would when I had something that suits my setup. Thanks again for your input, it was invaluable. I set up a SharedDriver class like you suggested but changed one or two things to take into account that I will be running each thread on a different connected device, meaning an individual AppiumDriver as opposed to a new WebDriver each time.

I solved this by putting in my BeforeClass method, a class to create a pool of all the devices I have connected. My SharedDriver then iterates through them using AtomicIntecger to remain thread-safe and adds the relevant driver to the factory.

I also liked the idea of running tests from the IDE on the first connected device for debugging and quick tests. Because BeforeClass doesn't run when running from within the IDE, my SharedDriver class checks for this, and if it hasn't run then it adds a single AppiumDriver for the first connected device and runs the test on that instead.

Sorry about the delay in coming back, I have been working on other items since. And thanks again for your help

Comment: I know that this splits the tests amongst potentially different devices (I aim to open x amount of emulators of the same device though) and therefore making it so each test won't run on all devices but it gives me quick feedback right now.

I'm looking into running entire suites on each connected device now though for more thorough test runs