# Not able to use Junit or TestNG Annotations like @BeforeClass @AfterClass while using Failsafe + Cucumber Parallel plugin

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, testng

I am trying to do Parallel testing using Selenium and Cucumber.So we have around 130 test scenarios which takes around 1.5 hours to run. Now By running all these tests in Parallel I can reduce the time.

I am using following 2 plugins:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>runner</outputDirectory>
                            <glue>
                                <package>${PackageName}</package>
                            </glue>
                            <featuresDirectory>${FeaturesDirectory}</featuresDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
                            <format>json</format>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <name>json</name>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                            <useTestNG>true</useTestNG>

                                                       <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                                        <execution>
                        <id>acceptance-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>

                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/Parallel*IT.class</include>
                            </includes>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>junit</name>
                                    <value>false</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

So the idea is, suppose I give Thread count or Fork count 3, it will invoke 3 browsers, and it will run the tests. With CUcumber JVM Parallel Plug in I have created 131 runner for all the scenarios. With @Before annotation from Cucumber, I can invoke the browser once, and for all the next instances it will use the same browser instance (Thus saving the time to open and close the browsers again and again.)

Now if we can use @BeforeClass or @AfterClass, this would have been much simpler solution. But as we can not. I had to use @Before, thus calling the same method again and again with each scenario.

```
import cucumber.api.java.Before;


public class stepdefs(){
static Browser browser;

    public static Scenario scenario;
    static TestConfiguration configuration = TestConfiguration.getConfiguration();
    @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {

        if (browser == null) {

            if (System.getProperty("seleniumRemoteWebDriver") == null) {

                WebTestSettings webTestSettings = configuration.getWebTestSettings();

                browser = Browser.LOAD_LOCAL_BROWSER(webTestSettings.externalBrowser, webTestSettings.driverPath);

            } else {
                if (System.getProperty("version") == null) {
                    browser = new RemoteBrowser(System.getProperty("browser"), System.getProperty("seleniumRemoteWebDriver"), System.getProperty("platform"));

                } else {
                    browser = new RemoteBrowser(System.getProperty("browser"), System.getProperty("seleniumRemoteWebDriver"), System.getProperty("platform"), System.getProperty("version"));
                }
            }

            TestContext.getContext().setBrowser(browser);


        }

        Browser browser = TestContext.getContext().getBrowser();
        this.scenario = scenario;
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
           }}
```

So this worked for @Before, but this will not work for @After. What I want to achieve here is to close all the browser instances after the test is done. But How do I know which 1 is the final instance? Or how do I close all the instances? Is there a way to use @AfterClass or @BeforeCLass or use SetupTeardown with JUnit/TestNG + Maven-Failsafe-plugin?

I have tried using Junit and TestNG both. I used to use a Runner file which extends to the SetupTearDown class for the non-parallel execution. But obviously can not use that as the runner classes are getting generated in runtime. Tried using pre-integration , post-integration phase as well. Which did not run. May be I am not using that phase correctly.

Comment: If u are using cucumber version greater than 4, then u should use in-built support for parallel execution whether junit or testng. https://cucumber.io/blog/announcing-cucumber-jvm-4-0-0/. It si cleaner and simpler. Regarding driver reuse u can store the drivers in a static ThreadLocal variable. This might help. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266736/cucumber-appium-where-to-store-hooks-if-initialising-driver-in-before. In fact the plugin creator ofcucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin advises to stop using the plugin https://github.com/temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin

Comment: Well Updating the cucumber file is not an option now as our project will need a lot of changes, even with that, I have tried used Cucumber 4. I have tried using the steps mentioned in the link you have provided for Cucumber 4, but it was simply not creating multiple browser instances. :( I will try again with TestNg may be that works. But that would be bit tricky as I will need to change a lot in this project to make it compatible with Cucumber 4.

Comment: Nevertheless, thank you for your reply. :)

Comment: So I tried with TestNg and CUcumber 4.2.6 but it keeps running all the tests in parallel, but in a same browser. Not sure how to Thread Safe a browser instance. Is there is a simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

***Lets move step by step. First we shall use Cucumber V starting from 4.0 onward as it supports parallel execution and we shall add below dependencies in order to implement it.***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then we shall start using maven-surefire plugin in order to actually run tests in parallel using parallel & threadCount properties as mentioned below -

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
        <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
        <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>   
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

*Depending on implementation, it would run test cases in different browser & close all. Now if you want to do something specific only once before or after the execution, you shall use @BeforeClass or @AfterClass in RunCuke Java file. Things are Thread Safe.*

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer @TheSociety. BUt the problem is, Surefire does not recognize BeforeClass or AfterClass hence it does not run it. It only runs Cucumber Related Methods/Annotations. Like Before and After. Which does not help in invoking the browser at the beginning and at the very end of the test.

Comment: Please understand @BeforeClass is invoked by JUnit/testNG using import org.junit.BeforeClass I have been running these for long. Please do not associate these methods with surefire. Surefire has nothing to do with these annotations.

Comment: Yes, @TheSociety that is the problem. Can you tell me how you run Junit tests using the surefire plugin? I have been trying to do that only. I mean how are you executing it? Either from command line maven or from an IDE like IntelliJ?

Answer (score -1):

Looking into your existing code it's not thread safe and will not allow you parallel execution because of static `Browser`.
You should try using [QAF - Pure TestNG implementation for BDD/Gherkin](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#bdd) Which provides [gherkin implementation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) that allows you to use all TestNG listener as well as have additional [listeners](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_listeners.html) for driver and element. Furthermore driver management taken care by qaf so you may not need to write additional code to manage driver or other test automation specific needs. qaf will take care of close all the browser instances after the test and will also allow you scenario level parallel execution.